# Regex to check for all letters in the alphabet

Tags: java, regex, expression, replaceall

I'm currently brushing up on my coding skills and working through some easy problems I've found online.  The particular task is to input a txt file that contains any number of lines, and to have the program check each line and return "True" or "False" depending on whether that line contains all 26 letters of the alphabet.  I feel like I'm almost finished, but my regular expression to match the string to [a-z] returns false no matter what I do.  I've tried changing the string to lowercase, removing spaces, and nothing seems to work.

[Here's a link to the project as well.](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/1pwl73/11413_challenge_139_easy_pangrams/)

The text I have in my text file currently is "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

```
package easy139;


import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


public class easy139 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                String noSpaces = line.replaceAll(" ","");
                if (noSpaces.matches("[a-z]")) {
                    System.out.println("True");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("False");
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you even do that with an efficient and not ridiculously long regex ?

Comment: That's not the correct approach. `[a-z]` stands for "one character contained in the a-z range (so basically, a letter)". `[a-z]{26}` would stand for "26 letters", without any constraint on *which* letters. You'll have to find another way !

Comment: That's what I was thinking too.  I tried replacing ["a-z"] with ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] and got the same results.  I've never used a regular expression before so I'm not quite sure what I'm trying is correct.

Comment: You could "sort" the string and then use a regex (i.e. `a+b+...`), but I don't see any direct solution using a regex and certainly the fastest one wouldn't be regex based here.

Comment: You can make a vector for each letter in alphabet. Then you loop the vector checking if the line has that letter with the expression `^.*[a].*$` (please, replace the `a` with the current letter). IF the line has all the letters, then return true.

Comment: Dystroy, do you think using a for loop that iterated through each letter of the alphabet and checked the string for an instance of each letter would be a better way to approach this?

Comment: @user2797124 yes, definitively. You could also iterate over the string and fill an array of boolean (using the int value of the char) and at the end check the array only has true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is returning false because the regex `[a-z]` means "exactly one letter".

A regex that works with `String.matches()` is:

```
(?i)(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)...(?=.*z).*
```

This uses one look ahead for each letter, each of which asserts that the letter is present.   The `(?i)` switch turns on case insensitivity.

Comment: Way too advanced for me even to think of its existence)

Comment: @Bohemian: does it really work? `"abc".matches("(?i)(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)")` is resulting in `false`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non regex based solution, in case you are interested in it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Set<Character> letters = new HashSet<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    try {
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            letters.clear();
            for (char c : in.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
                if (Character.isLetter(c)) letters.add(toLowerCase(c));
            }
            System.out.println(letters.size() == 26);
        }
    } finally { in.close(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract this in a new method and loop over all characters:

```
static boolean containsAllCharacters(String line) {
    if (line.length() < 26) {
        // if string is less than 26 characters long,
        // it won't hold all characters in it
        return false;
    }

    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        if (line.indexOf(c) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
String line = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);
System.out.println(containsAllCharacters(line) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

Comment: It is O(n * m) by time, where n is length of string and m is size of alphabet. My solution is just O(n) but requires O(m) additional memory, while your solution requires O(1) additional memory. That is why I called it inefficient, but it's surely could be debated.

Comment: This is pretty cool.  So I see that the for loop iterates through each letter one by one from a to z, but is this something built in to Java?  How exactly does it know the order of the alphabet automatically?

Comment: `'a'` is just a character presentation of the ASCII value **97**. `'z'` is the value **122**. With that you can add and substract your characters as you want. It would be the same looping from 97 till 122 and converting this number to a character to fit into the indexOf method.